# Linear Discriminant Analysis with scikit learn in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-discriminant

I am getting into machine learning and recently I have studied classification of linear separable data using linear Discriminant Analysis. To do so I have used the scikit-learn package and the function

```
.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
```

On data from MNIST database of handwritten digits. I have used the database to fit the model and do predictions on test data by doing like this:

```
LDA(n_components=2)
LDA_fit(data,labels)
LDA_predict(testdata)
```

Which works just fine. I get a nice accuracy rate of 95%. However the predict function uses data from all 784 dimensions (corresponding to images of 28x28 pixels). I don’t understand why all dimensions are used for the prediction?

I though the purpose of the linear Discriminant analysis is to find a projection on the low dimension space that allows maximizes class separation allowing, such that ideally data is linear separable and classification is easy.

What’s the point of LDA and determining the projection matrix if all 784 dimensions are used for prediction anyway?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

`discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` can be used to perform supervised dimensionality reduction, by projecting the input data to a linear subspace consisting of the directions which maximize the separation between classes (in a precise sense discussed in the mathematics section below). The dimension of the output is necessarily less than the number of classes, so this is, in general, a rather strong dimensionality reduction, and only makes sense in a multiclass setting.

This is implemented in `discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.transform`. The desired dimensionality can be set using the `n_components` constructor parameter. This parameter **has no influence** on `discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.fit` or `discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.predict`.

Meaning `n_components` is used only for `transform` or `fit_transform`.  You can use dimensionality reduction for removing noise from your data or for visualization.

Comment: Thanks Farseer. Based on your lighting, I have improved my solution for sklearn implementation. By theory you can have the prediction be done on n_components, but it is not adopted itseems

Answer (score 0):

The low dimension which you had mentioned is actually `n_classes` in terms of classification.

If you use this for dimension reduction technique you can chose `n_components` dimensions, if you had specified it (it must be < `n_classes`). This has no impact on prediction as mentioned in documentation.

Hence, once you give input data, it will transform the data into `n_classes` dimensional space, then use this space for training/prediction. [Reference](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py#L718) - `_decision_function()` is used for prediction.

You can use Transform(X) to view the new lower dimensional space learned by the model.

Answer (score -1):

Applying LDA on mnist data with reduced dimensions:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(data_1000, labels_1000).transform(data_1000)

# LDA before tsne
plt.figure()
colors = ['brown','black','deepskyblue','red','yellow','darkslategrey','navy','darkorange','deeppink', 'lawngreen']
target_names  = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
lw = 2
y = labels_1000

plt.figure()
for color, i, target_name in zip(colors, [0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], target_names):
plt.scatter(X_r2[y == i, 0], X_r2[y == i, 1], alpha=.8, color=color,
            label=target_name)
plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=False, scatterpoints=1)
plt.title('LDA of MNIST dataset before TSNE')

plt.show()
```